# How to make Web API method POST in PHP

Tags: php, api

I have this script

```
<?php
include_once "fungsi.php";
include_once "conf/conf_Star04.php";;
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
        if(!isset($_POST['card'])){
            $json = array("status" => 0,"Desc" => "Error", "message" => "Please insert CardNumber");
        }else{
            $card = $_POST['card'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $address = $_POST['address'];
            $hp = $_POST['hp'];
            // QUERY HERE
            $sql = "MY Query";
            $result = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
            if ($result){
                $json = array("status" => 1,"Desc" => "Done");
            }else{
                $json = array("status" => 0,"Desc" => "Error");
            }
        }
    }else{
        $json = array("status" => 0,"Desc" => "Error");
    }
?>
```

I make API POST method. What is wrong with that script?

When I access, it always give error **Undefined variable: json**

Answer (score 0):

you are not initialize **$json** variable properly , try below code thisa may help...

```
 <?php
    include_once "fungsi.php";
    include_once "conf/conf_Star04.php";;
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

    $json = array("status" => 1);

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    if(!isset($_POST['card'])){
        echo "Please insert CardNumber";
    }else{
        $card = $_POST['card'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $address = $_POST['address'];
        $hp = $_POST['hp'];
        // QUERY HERE
        $sql = "MY Query";

        $result = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
        if ($result){

            $json["status"] = 1;
            $json["Desc"] = "Done";
            echo json_encode($json);
        }else{

            $json["status"] = 0;
            $json["Desc"] = "Error";
            echo json_encode($json);
        }
    }
    }else{

    $json["status"] = 0;
    $json["Desc"] = "Error";
    echo json_encode($json);
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: as u see my code, where is wrong code, I can access it in header parameters, i still get Desc error even i have put all correct parammerters in header,, Is That above correct scrip API method post?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is at this line --> `echo "Please insert CardNumber";`

At the end of the code, you are doing `echo json_encode($json);`, so it is expecting `$json` variable.

Hence, you should change this line:

`echo "Please insert CardNumber";`

to

```
$json = array("status" => 0,"Desc" => "Error", "message" => "Please insert CardNumber");
```

Comment: I have edited my question, even I using your code and I set parameter for card, $card is not show **Undefined index: card**, why is it?

Comment: Show us what parameters you are posting and what errors you are getting..

Comment: I use my question script, my parameters card, email, address, hp using post method it throw please enter your cardnumber, Is my script wrong, so i cannot get header parammeters